# Shared Preference gets updated only after app restart

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I store a shared preference in one of my activity.The preference gets stored  but when that activity is finished and returns back to the main activity where i check for my stored shared preference,it returns false(no shared preference).Once i restarted my application,the same shared preference is checked where it states,it has some values.
In short , shared preference values are getting updated only after app restart.

```
Main Activity(Calling Settings Activity):
 Intent intent = new Intent(Voiceanswer.this, SettingsActivity.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 108);


Settings Activity:(onCreate)
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getSharedPreferences("trial",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("flag",false);
    boolean trialflag=editor.commit();
```

Finish of Settings Activity:

```
SettingsActivity.this.finish();
```

Main Activity(on Resume)

```
SharedPreferences voiceTemp=getSharedPreferences("trial",MODE_PRIVATE);

       if(voiceTemp.contains("flag"))
            Log.d(TAG, "Contains key flag");

      boolean trialflag=voiceTemp.getBoolean("flag",true);
```

Before App restart,after settingsactivity finish:

```
voiceTemp.contains("flag") returns false.
trialflag=true;
```

After App restart:

```
voiceTemp.contains("flag") returns true.
trialflag=false;
```

Comment: try to use apply() instead of commit?

Comment: I tried both apply and commit no luck.After storing of shared preference values ,i checked manually,whether preference xml is stored with those value and the value was there.So no issue in storing,the only issue is in retirving when it came back to main activity.

Answer (score 0):

https://riptutorial.com/android/example/4983/commit-vs--apply

If another editor on this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits(apply) are completed as well as any other sync commits that may be pending.

Comment: as you can see in the code above,i created new instance of shared preference and not even tried to reuse it.So there's no question of blockage.